# Ion auth register user without activation from admin panel

Tags: php, ion-auth

I'm using the Ion Auth library for the authorisation in my CodeIgniter project. I would like to have the following options in my project:

- If a user registers via the front-end of the website, he or she needs to activate their account via an activation e-mail. I know this option can be set via the config file.
- As an administrator, I want to be able to create a new user account and choose if the account is active or not. If I choose the account to be active, no activation e-mail has to be sent. If I choose the account to be inactive, the activation e-mail should be sent.

Is this possible via the Ion Auth library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use register() function.
http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#register

You can change function to automatically set inactive status, and approve only in admin area